# .NET SDK Azure EventHub - Authenticating Consumer/Receiver using Active Directory Client Id and Secret Value

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

Can some one provide a .NET **C#** sample on how to instantiate EventProcessorClient object as a RECEIVER using Azure's Active Directory RBAC using TenantID, Client ID and Secret ?

I would like to build a consumer piece which access a single partition in Event Hub.

I have searched the earth and there is not event a single example which explains that. The articles i did find only uses SAS Connection String approach.

using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor 5.4.1
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small snippet as a starting point for you. EventProcessorClient also takes TokenCredential as a parameter so it should also work in a similar way.

```
TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredential("<tenant-id>", "<client-id>", "<client-secret>");
var fullyQualifiedNamespace = "<ehnamespace>.servicebus.windows.net";
var eventHubName = "<eventhubname>";
var consumerGroup = "<consumergroupname";

var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(
                consumerGroup,
                fullyQualifiedNamespace,
                eventHubName,
                credential);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, this issue is resolved.